# Cannot access this whilst debouncing search request in Vue with Lodash?

Tags: vue.js, lodash

I have a simple search input:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="search">
</div>
```

When you enter a value it will query a remote API to fetch and then display the data:

```
...
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    people: []
    search: ''
  },
  watch: {
    search() {
      // Rate limit
      this.debouncedSearch()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    debouncedSearch: _.debounce(() => {
      console.log(this)
      // self = this
      // io.socket.put('/search', this.search, (people, jwres) => {
      // self.people = people
      // })
    }, 500)
  },
  created(){
    this.people = locals.people
  }
})
```

The problem here is that `console.log(this)` returns `undefined`.

I have used this in another application and it works so battling to understand why not here.

Is there something that I have done wrong there, seems to be correct but no matter what I try I cannot access the scope of the Vue application in that debouncedSearch method?

Answer (score 7):

To solve the issue just replace the arrow function with function() {}

Replace this:

```
methods: {
    debouncedSearch: _.debounce(() => {
      console.log(this) // undefined
    }, 500)
  },
```

With This:

```
methods: {
    debouncedSearch: _.debounce(function () {
      console.log(this) // not undefined
    }, 500)
  },
```

Hope to help others took me a lot of time to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure your problem is the use of the `this`-preserving function style. You need a way to refer to the Vue object you're creating (it's not `this` at the point your debounce function is defined). One way would be to do

```
const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  ...
  methods: {
    debouncedSearch: _.debounce(() => {
      console.log(vm)
      // io.socket.put('/search', vm.search, (people, jwres) => {
      // vm.people = response
      // })
    }, 500)
  },
```

Comment: He is using arrow function here - shouldn't this value be inherited from parent scope in this case vue instance ?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I think I understand what you're saying here but not exactly sure that I understand why. Alright so then `console.log(vm.search)` shows the search value as expected but if `vm.people = people` does not change the list of people even though new data was returned, it's like the data binding has no effect?

Comment: @CraigvanTonder could you just store your vue instance into variable and keep things as before ?

Comment: @BelminBedak Tried your suggestion but it still returns `this` as undefined.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yokoqafowe/edit?html,js,output pretty same thing here with setTimeout but it works as expected.Maybe lodash mess something, I don't know...

Comment: @BelminBedak, it's a mix of things but i think either babel or lodash are at fault here. `_.debounce(function () {` without the arrow function works with my code.

Comment: @BelminBedak Your `setTimeout` example works because it is inside the method body of `changeIt`. `debouncedSearch` is not inside a method body. Understanding `this` can be tricky. Maybe look at https://www.codementor.io/dariogarciamoya/understanding--this--in-javascript-du1084lyn